# Relation between Weierstrass zeta function and Weierstrass sigma function

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-equations

Given a $2d$ lattice $\mathbb{\Omega}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ and $ [x],[y] \in \mathbb{C}/ \mathbb{\Omega} $, where $[x] \neq \pm [y]$, define $f(z) = \zeta_\mathbb{\Omega}(x)+\zeta_\mathbb{\Omega}(y)+\zeta_\mathbb{\Omega}(z)-\zeta_\mathbb{\Omega}(x+y+z),$  where $\zeta_\mathbb{\Omega}(z)$ is the Weierstrass zeta function for $\mathbb{\Omega}$ . I have figured out that the zeros of $f$ are $(-x+\mathbb{\Omega}) \cup(-y+\mathbb{\Omega})$ and the poles of $f$ are $(-x-y+\mathbb{\Omega}) \cup\mathbb{\Omega}$, hence $f(z)=a \cdot \frac{\sigma_\Omega(y+z)\sigma_\Omega(x+z)}{\sigma_\Omega(z)\sigma_\Omega(x+y+z)}$ for some constant $a$ independent of $z$.  Here $\sigma_\Omega(z)$ is the Weierstrass $\sigma $ function. How can I determine what $a$ is ? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: $1/a = \frac{\sigma_\Omega(y)\sigma_\Omega(x)}{\sigma_\Omega(x+y)}$

Comment: @reuns Could you please elaborate on how you got that? I tried using limits but it wasn't very helpful

Comment: Just the residue at the simple pole $z=0$ (using that $\lim z \zeta_\Omega(z)=1$)

Comment: @reuns Thank you so much. I got it now.